# Routing Internet traffic through computer on another subnet

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, subnet

Ubuntu box ***server***  has 2 network interfaces:

```
eth0 50.57.71.100
eth1 10.182.161.100
```

Ubuntu box ***client*** has 1 network interface:

```
eth0 10.177.30.100
```

***server*** and  ***client*** can already talk to each other just fine.   Here is  ***client***'s routing table:

```
10.176.0.0/12 via 10.177.0.1 dev eth0 
10.177.0.0/17 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.177.30.100
10.208.0.0/12 via 10.177.0.1 dev eth0
```

I have enabled ipv4 forwarding on  **server**'s kernel.    How can I set this up so any internet traffic from machine ***client*** gets routed through  ***server***? (like say, ping 8.8.8.8)

I tried adding a route on  ***client*** but lost all network connectivity until I deleted it:

```
route add 10.182.161.100/32 dev eth0
```

I tried setting a  ***client***'s default gateway to  ***server*** but this fails:

```
# route add default gw 10.182.161.100
SIOCADDRT: No such process
```

Comment: Could you add output of the "# traceroute 10.182.161.100" executed from the client to the question?

Comment: please add the output of ip route list for both server and client, this is just too confusing otherwise. You will need to enabled ip forwarding on the server for it to be able to route the clients traffic and most likely also MASQUERADE it via netfilter because generally RFC1918 networks like the 10.x.x.x ones you are using internally are not being routed in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want traffic from a network behind router `10.177.0.1` to go out through a different route (to server specifically), set the route up in `10.177.0.1` pointing to **server**.

This would direct all outgoing traffic that passes through `10.177.0.1` through server, and I am not sure that is what you want.

Comment: thanks, is this the only way?  what if I only have access to 'client' and 'server' and lack access to any routers in between.  Does this make my scenario impossible?  Or maybe its doable with a VPN of some sort?

Comment: Not impossible, just extremely difficult. A VPN or some other tunneling protocol would help a lot.

Comment: If the router supports [policy based routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing), you could define a route based on the source address. But without using some kind of tunnel, you can't achieve what you want without control of all routers in between

Answer (score 0):

You could install an [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openvpn.html) server on your server and a client on your client. Using "redirect-gateway def1" the default route of your client is redirected to your server.
After you have a working OpenVPN setup, you have to deploy NAT (masquerading) to get rid of the clients private ip on the internet side.

**UPDATE:**
After Andrew Schulmans comment I researched a bit further.
Because your goal is not security of the tunnel, a [GRE](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.tunnel.gre.html) tunnel will suit your needs better and is easier to setup.
In your case the default route of the client needs to point to the server and you have to do masquerading:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

To make iptables rules persistent:

```
service iptables save
```

Comment: Installing OpenVPN is way overkill to solve a routing problem.

Comment: Without control of the routers in between, this is a tunneling problem. Of course there could be an easier way to setup a tunnel for general use (tunnel all traffic from client to server).